# Error handling in the cycle for()

Tags: error-handling, try-catch

How to make the cycle `for()` to restart or skip when there is an error?

My code moves on web pages, but fails on a non-existent page and returns an error and stops.

I tried `try-catch`, but I did not understand how to do a re-start or skip.

It should be a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function A() {
  // do something
}

function B() {
  try {
    // A();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    log ( e );
    A();
  }
  finally {
    // whatever you want whether theres an exception or not
  }
}
```

I don't know if this might work, but it worths a try.